# Get Css value in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I currently have an element with HTML as below

```
<span class="onoffswitch-inner" id="aui_3_4_0_1_549">
    ::before
    ::after
</span>
```

This element has a visible text is "YES" or "NO". When I click on it, its text changes into "NO" or "YES".

I believe its text control by css. But I couldnot get it using Selenium

All css snippet as below

```
.onoffswitch-inner {
display: block;
margin-left: -100%;
transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
width: 200%;
}

.onoffswitch-inner::before {
    background-color: #87b467;
    color: #fff;
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner::after {
    background-color: #b95356;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

What I tried so far

```
WebElement object = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//span[@class='onoffswitch-inner']");
System.out.println(object.getCssValue("content")); // It returns empty string
```

What did I do wrong?

If I want to get the text "Yes"/"No", what I need to do?

Many thanks

Comment: i guess you're want to get css value of pseudo-element ':after', not element itself. So, somehow like `"//span[@class='onoffswitch-inner']::after"` should work

Comment: I have this exception: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@class='onoffswitch-inner']::after because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@class='onoffswitch-inner']::after' is not a valid XPath expression. >>>>>> Seem the pseudo-element locator is not supported by webdriver

Comment: @NguyenVuHoang: same problem, any progress?